# Is there an implementation of Convolutional Neural Network available in OpenCV or similar?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Is there a Convolutional Neural Network in OpenCV? How possible is it to use the algorithm for image or video processing?

Comment: no, there isn't anything like that in opencv (yet) [there is a MLP-NN, but that's not convolutional]. look at caffe, theano, torch, or the like.

Comment: This is something that is candidate for [Google Summer of Code 2015](http://code.opencv.org/projects/opencv/wiki/GSoC_2015): "It would be cool if OpenCV could load and run deep networks trained with popular DNN packages like Caffe, Theano or Torch."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No.

There is no directly implemented convnet library bundled into OpenCV, however Caffe (one of the leading convolutional neural network packages) interacts with it rather well.

- If you install Caffe, one of its requisites is OpenCV, and you can then use OpenCV through Caffe's C or Python API's. See [main Caffe website](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/).
- If you install OpenCV (a recent enough version) you can use the new opencv_dnn module to interact with Caffe. See [opencv_dnn tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html).

Comment: Which one do you recommend to learn for beginners? Opencv+Caffe or tensorflow?