# What is the best convolutional neural networks (CNN) library for OpenCV? (with simple implementation and example)

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, deep-learning, opencv3.0

What is the best convolutional neural networks (CNN) library for OpenCV?
(with simple implementation and example)

Comment: in C++ not python. Also, can be use with AMD graphic card.

Comment: Closing as tool rec. Or dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29130983/is-there-an-implementation-of-convolutional-neural-network-available-in-opencv-o

Answer (score 3):

1. ConvNet - C++ library for convolutional neural networks

   http://conv-net.sourceforge.net/doc/

ConvNet is a C++ library implementing data propagation throught convolutional neural networks.

2. tiny-cnn: A header-only, dependency-free deep learning framework for C++11

   https://github.com/nyanp/tiny-cnn